# Doubt in the definition of the stress-energy tensor in Peskin and Schroeder's QFT book

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

We can describe the infinitesimal translation
$$
x^{\mu} \to x^{\mu}-a^{\mu}
$$
alternatively as a transformation of the field configuration
$$
\phi(x) \to \phi(x+a) = \phi(x) + a^{\mu} \phi(x).
$$
The Lagrangian is also a scalar, so
$$
\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{L} + a^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L} a^{\nu} \partial_{\mu} (\delta_{\nu}^{\mu} \mathcal{L}).
$$

If we compare this to equation
$$
\mathcal{L}(x) \to \mathcal{L}(x) + \alpha \partial_{\mu} \mathcal{J}(x)
$$
we see that we now have a nonzero $\mathcal{J}^{\mu}$.

Up to this point, I basically copied Peskin and Schroeder's book "An Introduction to QFT". Then, they state: "Taking this into account, we can apply the theorem to obtain four separately conserved currents:"

$$
T^{\mu}_{\nu} \equiv \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu} \phi)} \partial_{\nu} \phi - \mathcal{L} \delta^{\mu}_{\nu}
$$
this last equation corresponds to (2.17) in the book, but I really cannot see how we get there. The fact that $\mathcal{J}$ is a vector (rank-1 tensor), not a tensor (rank-2 tensor), as the SET was defined, stands as my main issue.

Comment: For each of the four translations ($x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$) you have a four-component conserved current $\mathcal J^\mu$. The stress-energy tensor combines them into a $4\times 4=16$ component object.

Comment: Maybe good if you fix some typos: a couple of partial derivatives, a plus, and an index missing at least